# How to fix the Autowired in an External jar import

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm having a well working library and I would like to utilize the library in one of my sample Spring boot console application.

I built the library using the command `mvn clean install` and the newly generated .jar file I imported in my sample Spring boot console application.

I created a bean in my new sample application and tried to create an object of `UserManagementService`, which is in the external *.jar* and the said *jar* internally has two properties

**External Jar's - Service file**

```
public class UserManagementService {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    ManagementService managementService;

    public String getUserFirstName(String userName) {
        return userService.getUserFirstName(userName);
    }


    .. Rest of the implementation
}
```

These two autowired is not working and it has the value null moreover it throws an exception `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class...`

**My Sample Application:**

```
public class ApplicationBean {

    private UserManagementService userService = new UserManagementService();

    public void run() {
        if(userService == null) {
            System.out.println("Oops");
        }

        String userFirstName = userService.getUserFirstName("Emma");
        ... Rest of the implementation
    }
}
```

Kindly assist me how to fix this.

Comment: if you Autowire UserManagementService, is it working?

Comment: @jpganz18 - No, its not working.

Comment: can you check at your library if it has a @Configuration file? You might need to import it manually into your context

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare your user management service as a bean in order to be able to inject it.

**First Approach**
Annotate the `UserManagementService` class with `@Service` if you have control over the library, `UserService` and `ManagementService` needs to be annotated with `@Service` too so they can be injected into `UserManagementService`. You may need to use `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "libray.package" })` in your spring app (over main class) to make it scan your library and load the services.

**Second Approach**
You make your library framework independent and make `UserManagementService` a simple POJO where you pass `UserService` and `ManagementService` as constructor arguments, then declare those beans in your spring app

```
public class ApplicationBean {
  @Bean
  public UserService userServiceProvider(){
  return new UserService();
  }
  @Bean
  public ManagementService managementServiceProvider(){
  return new ManagementService();
  }
  @Bean
  public UserManagementService userManagementServiceProvider(UserService userService, ManagementService managementService){
  return new UserManagementService(userService, managementService);
  }
}
```

These beans declaration go to application main class or to a class annotated with `@Configuration`

Comment: Still I'm getting the exception `Field userRepository` and I'm getting a additional action message `Consider defining a bean of type 'org.payroll.UserRepository' in your configuration.` which is used in the `UserManagementService` and the `UserRepository` extends the `JpaRepository`

Comment: So let me edit the answer according to the new information

Comment: Yeah sure. Still the autowired property of `userService`  and `managementService` not finding a suitable bean in the external jar.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are injecting a bean into another bean, so both sides of the injection needs to be beans